com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
The very code which was working before has stopped working now and I'm clueless as to what has caused this or how to fix this.
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:460)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:137)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:294)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:412)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:375)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:279) 

Previously I was using Jenkins and Nexus, but now I use Azure Pipelines and ACR and maybe that has affected? Maybe because of different Java version in Azure machine?
